# AsyncApi Change npm registry url

Tags: asyncapi

Is there are command-line switch to point the npm registry to different url? I have created a template and published to our company's registry. When referring the package, it is referring to  https://registry.npmjs.org/. I did install the template locally using

```
C:\>npm install -g @company/asyncapi-csharp-template

C:\>ag DomainServiceA.yml @company/asyncapi-csharp-template -o ouput
```

and the error response is

> Something went wrong:
> HttpErrorGeneral: 404 Not Found - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@company%2fasyncapi-csharp-template - Not found

Answer (score 0):

Tbh best if you submit issue here https://github.com/asyncapi/generator/issues   as normally it should work.

also try to add `--debug` flag to understand more what is happening with template usage in generator